# Python requests is too slow with certain WI-FI connection

Tags: python, wifi, python-3, ipv6

I'm working on a TTS app using AWS Polly in Raspberry PI 3 B+ and when I post a text using Python `requests` it take a long time receive the response, around **16-17 seconds**. This happens only with a certain wifi connection. I have tried 3 different wifi connections in which 2 of them are mobile hot spots and the `request.post` gives a response within **2 seconds**. When I connect to a wifi modem which is a 4G/5G connection it takes around **16-17 seconds**. Modem speed is not an issue here as it gives minimum 120Mbps speed. Pi connects only with the 4G connection here not 5G.
I have enabled the "`Disable IPV6`" option in in the wifi settings.
Why it's slow only with a certain connection which is a faster network?

```
import requests
import time

start = time.time()
res = requests.post('https://myawsAPI_XXXXXXX', json={"body":"Activate barn door protocol."})
print("Elapsed time1:", time.time() - start)
```

> Blockquote

*Elapsed time1: 17.350016117095947*

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem here. I had to disable the Ipv6 in the pi `sysctl.conf`.

To disable ipv6, you have to open `/etc/sysctl.conf` using any text editor and insert the following lines at the end:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

and reboot. If IPv6 is still not disabled, then the problem is that `sysctl.conf` is still not activated. To solve this, type the command:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

You will see this in the terminal:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

After that, if you run:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

If you see 1, ipv6 has been successfully disabled.
For other methods please check this [page](https://www.howtoraspberry.com/2020/04/disable-ipv6-on-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: You should also mark your answer as the answer to your question